# Find words containing at least three instances of a letter

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Ex: Find words in "words.txt" with at least three a or A (both capital and small) letters. (Hint: You should probably use cat command, then, feed its output into grep command.)

I have tried some ways but  I found like `___sss__`, `eee___`.

My list:

```
Ababdeh
Ababua
abac
abaca
abacate
abacay
```

I have to find:

```
Ababua
abaca
abacate
abacay
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO. Also please make your samples of input and expected output more clear in your question.

Comment: Judging from the `Hint:` the person assigning the exercise doesn't know any more about bash than you do. Avoid all *UUOc*s (*Unnecessary Use Of* `cat`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a capturing group and backreferences.

```
grep -Ei '(.).*\1.*\1' words.txt
```

If there is a certain letter to look for, let's say `a`, that's easier.

```
grep -i 'a.*a.*a' words.txt
```

Comment: Okay, that's slick and shorter than what I was thinking (by a factor of 4)